# How to launch a fragment, from an image adapter?

Tags: android

I would like to open a new fragment upon clicking on the imageView in the ImageAdapter class. However I can't seem to manage to do so. I am new to android studio, so maybe I am missing out on some important information. Do you have any recommendations on how to do so. I have tried to use fragment transactions to launch them however I can't seem to do much since I am not in the fragment class itself nor in an activity.

**Image Adapter Class**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageView imageView;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300,300));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageURI(mThumbIds[position]);
    //check for tap
    if(imageView.getDrawable() != null)
    {
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       **//LAUNCH FRAGMENT HERE.** 
            }
        });
    }
    return imageView;
}



private Uri[] mThumbIds = new Uri[20];

public void setUriArr(Uri[] uriArr){
    this.mThumbIds = uriArr;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you want to launch a Fragment or an Activity? You need an Activity to hold a Fragment, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to use fragment transactions to launch them however I can't seem to do much since I am not in the fragment class itself nor in an activity.

You could simply pass in a FragmentManager

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    private Context mContext;
    private FragmentManager mFragManager;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, FragmentManager fm) {
        mContext = c;
        mFragManager = fm;   
    }
```

Then use it elsewhere to make the fragment transactions.

Wherever you create the adapter should have access to a FragmentManager via the Activity or Fragment itself.

Make sure that you are using the correct import here depending on if you want to use Support Fragments, or not.